# Multidimensional 2d array sort

Tags: php, sorting, multidimensional-array

here is my array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [product_option_id] => 1072
            [option_id] => 5
            [name] => Sizes
            [type] => select
            [option_value] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [product_option_value_id] => 8282
                            [option_value_id] => 57
                            [name] => 10
                            [price] => 
                            [price_prefix] => +
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [product_option_value_id] => 8283
                            [option_value_id] => 58
                            [name] => 11
                            [price] => 
                            [price_prefix] => +
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [product_option_value_id] => 8284
                            [option_value_id] => 59
                            [name] => 12
                            [price] => 
                            [price_prefix] => +
                        )

                    [3] => Array
                        (
                            [product_option_value_id] => 8285
                            [option_value_id] => 60
                            [name] => 13
                            [price] => 
                            [price_prefix] => +
                        )

                    [4] => Array
                        (
                            [product_option_value_id] => 8279
                            [option_value_id] => 61
                            [name] => 7
                            [price] => 
                            [price_prefix] => +
                        )

                    [5] => Array
                        (
                            [product_option_value_id] => 8280
                            [option_value_id] => 62
                            [name] => 8
                            [price] => 
                            [price_prefix] => +
                        )

                    [6] => Array
                        (
                            [product_option_value_id] => 8281
                            [option_value_id] => 63
                            [name] => 9
                            [price] => 
                            [price_prefix] => +
                        )

                )

            [required] => 1
        )

)
```

is it possible to sort by [option_value][$i][name] ? so output of this should be:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [product_option_id] => 1072
            [option_id] => 5
            [name] => Sizes
            [type] => select
            [option_value] => Array
                (


                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [product_option_value_id] => 8279
                            [option_value_id] => 61
                            [name] => 7
                            [price] => 
                            [price_prefix] => +
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [product_option_value_id] => 8280
                            [option_value_id] => 62
                            [name] => 8
                            [price] => 
                            [price_prefix] => +
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [product_option_value_id] => 8281
                            [option_value_id] => 63
                            [name] => 9
                            [price] => 
                            [price_prefix] => +
                        )
                    [3] => Array
                        (
                            [product_option_value_id] => 8282
                            [option_value_id] => 57
                            [name] => 10
                            [price] => 
                            [price_prefix] => +
                        )

                    [4] => Array
                        (
                            [product_option_value_id] => 8283
                            [option_value_id] => 58
                            [name] => 11
                            [price] => 
                            [price_prefix] => +
                        )

                    [5] => Array
                        (
                            [product_option_value_id] => 8284
                            [option_value_id] => 59
                            [name] => 12
                            [price] => 
                            [price_prefix] => +
                        )

                    [6] => Array
                        (
                            [product_option_value_id] => 8285
                            [option_value_id] => 60
                            [name] => 13
                            [price] => 
                            [price_prefix] => +
                        )

                )

            [required] => 1
        )

)
```

I lost many hours on this, if somebody could, please help me with it (tryed array_multisort but no result)

Comment: Please show us what have you tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP >= 5.5.0 needed for `array_column()` or use the [PHP Implementation of array_column()](https://github.com/ramsey/array_column/blob/master/src/array_column.php)

```
array_multisort(array_column($array[0]['option_value'], 'name'),
                SORT_ASC, $array[0]['option_value']);
```